# Symmetric property of $x \in G$ such that $a = xbx^{-1}$

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am working through Charles Pinter's A Book on Abstract Algebra.

One of the problems is to prove the equivalence relation iff there is an $x \in G$ such that $a = xbx^{-1}$

To show the reflexive is easy.
If $x = a$ then $a = xax^{-1} = aaa^{-1} =a$ 
Also if $x = e$ then $a = xax^{-1} =  eae^{-1}=a$

The symmetric proof is where I am confused: 
Suppose $a = xbx^{-1}$
$x^{-1}a = x^{-1}xbx^{-1}$
$x^{-1}ax = x^{-1}xbx^{-1}x$
$x^{-1}ax = b$
But this is obviously not symmetric.
What am I missing here or conflating?

Transitivity
Seems easy.
Suppose $a,b,c, x, y \in G$
and $a= xbx^{-1}$ and $b= ycy^{-1}$.
Then we can have $a = xycy^{-1}x^{-1}$ ...For substituting for b
$a = (xy)c(xy)^{-1}$... Because (y^{-1}x^{-1} = (xy)^{-1}
Since $xy,(xy)^{-1} \in G$ We met transitivity check.

Thus $a$ $b$ equivalence relation proved.

Comment: If $x \in G$ then $x^{-1} \in G.$  When you show $b = x^{-1}a x$ then $b$ is indeed related to $a$

Comment: Oh so we are saying any x. That makes total sense then. Is that correct? $a = xbx^{1}$ then $b = yby^{1}$ is what we are saying? Where in this case $y=x^{-1}$?

Comment: $a$ is related to $b$ if there is a member of the group (any $x\in G$) such that $a = xbx^{-1}.$  You could also say that if we take every member of $G$ and calculate $gag^{-1},$ it will generate a subset of $G$ (called the conjugacy class) and all of the members of this subset are related to one another.

Comment: You  appear to be misunderstanding what "$b= xax^{-1}$ MEANS.  It means that, for this specific pair, a, b, there  EXIST some x so that is true.  It does NOT mean that the same "x" must work for every a and b.   If $b= xax^{-1}$ then $x^{-1}bx= a$.   We are just using "$x^{-1}$"  as "x" now.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{alignat}{1}
&a\sim b \iff \\
&\exists x\in G\mid a=xbx^{-1} \iff \\
&\exists x\in G\mid b=x^{-1}ax \iff \\
&\exists x'(:=x^{-1})\in G\mid b=x'ax'^{-1} &\iff\\
&b\sim a
\end{alignat}

Comment: In English can you say what the second to last line is saying?

Comment: If $a$ is equivalent to $b$, then $a=xbx^{-1}$ for *some* $x\in G$. But then $b=x'ax'^{-1}$ for *some* $x'\in G$ (take $x'=x^{-1}$). Therefore $b$ is equivalent to $a$.